# Simulating mouse drag to move files on Windows using UIAutomation

Tags: automation, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, simulation, ui-automation

I have a funtion to simulate mouse drag from an element to another:

```
public void do_drag(IUIAutomationElement from_element, IUIAutomationElement to_element) {
    int from_x = (int)(from_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.left + from_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.right) / 2;
    int from_y = (int)(from_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.top + from_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.bottom) / 2;
    int to_x = (int)(to_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.left + to_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.right) / 2;
    int to_y = (int)(to_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.top + to_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.bottom) / 2;
    var screenBounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    SetCursorPos(from_x, from_y); 
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTTF_LEFTDOWN, from_x, from_y, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTTF_MOVE, to_x * 65535 / screenBounds.Width, to_y * 65535 / screenBounds.Height, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTTF_LEFTUP, to_x, to_y, 0, 0);
    return;
}
```

It worked when I simulating dragging from one cell to another in an excel file to select multiple grids:

[image]

Now I want to simulate an action which dargs a file to a folder to move the file. The mouse moved as expectation, but it did not actually move the file to the folder. Can anyone help me? Thanks soo much!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have found the point: I added a small move before move to the target element (to simulate dragging and hesitating and pausing lol) then it worked. Seems like the system will detect my move pattern, but I still cannot know the specific rules. Anyway I can move files now.

```
public bool do_move(IUIAutomationElement from_element, IUIAutomationElement to_element) {
    int from_x = (int)(from_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.left + from_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.right) / 2;
    int from_y = (int)(from_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.top + from_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.bottom) / 2;
    int to_x = (int)(to_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.left + to_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.right) / 2;
    int to_y = (int)(to_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.top + to_element.CurrentBoundingRectangle.bottom) / 2;
    var screenBounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    SetCursorPos(from_x, from_y);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTTF_LEFTDOWN, from_x, from_y, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTTF_MOVE, -10, 0, 0, 0);
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTTF_MOVE, to_x * 65535 / screenBounds.Width, to_y * 65535 / screenBounds.Height, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTTF_LEFTUP, to_x, to_y, 0, 0);
    return true;
}
```